# SFTP in a cron job

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, sftp

### Issue

1. I want to automate downloading a file via SFTP
2. I set up an SFTP server and a keying mechanism
3. I have created a simple bash script - **script.sh**
4. I added an entry in cron for the script

The script, **script.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash  
sftp user@server:/home/user/file.txt  
exit 0
```

Executing the script manually works fine (text file is saved in home directory), but adding **script.sh** (with proper permissions) to `crontab` does nothing.

The crontab entry:

```
* * * * * /home/user/script.sh
```

For authentication I used `ssh-keygen` to create a set of keys (private, public) and set up cross authentication to the SFTP server.

For script automation I used `keychain` for password-less authentication.

### Currently

Currently, I have a script called **script.sh** located in the *"user"* home directory (`/home/user/`).

When run by `root` manually, the script gets the file from the SFTP server, and places it in `/home/user/`.

It does not perform this action when run from a `cron` job. In `cron`, the `sftp` command gets an error.

Ideas?

### Working on it

1. Changing the **HOME** variable on `/etc/crontab` did not solve the issue
2. Stating full paths in **script.sh** did not solve the issue
3. Stating **PATH** variable in **script.sh** did not solve the issue
4. I catched the error from the `sftp` command - it's **255**

executing the script manually (`./script.sh`) still works flawlessly though...

Comment: please post the crontab entry here

Comment: How do you authenticate to the server? What user is running your crontab entry? Where is the `script.sh` located?

Comment: @StefK, crontab posted :)

Comment: @Jakuje, I use `keygen` to create authentication keys, and I use `keychain` to automate the username and password exchange. The `crontab` job is run by root, and script.sh is located at the user's home directory - /home/user/

Comment: The `root` does not have any access to your keys. You should run the crontab job as your user.

Comment: it may be more convenient to run the job (script) as a non root user as its just a remote request and has nothing to do to your local system administration.

Comment: the job is run by root for security reasons. I built the entire keying system so that the root user would be able to perform this. when I say that I execute the script manually - I mean I execute it as the root user. not only the root has access to the keys - he's the only one that has access to them. the user "user" does not hold any ssh keys.

Comment: thanks to both of you for your assistance, BTW :)  please note my edit regarding the error from sftp

Comment: @dsblind please [edit] your question to explain exactly how you are running the job and how the authentication is performed. Also please clarify what you mean by "does nothing" - does the job run but fail to authenticate, or not run at all (you may need to look in syslog if you have not arranged for cron output to be mailed to you). As it stands there is not enough information to do anything but guess.

Comment: @steeldriver, I edited my question. What I want the system to do is place the text file in the user's home folder :)

Comment: Use `sftp -vvv` and add the output to the question, so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: Be sure you are using ssh-keygen, then ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <target computer> in order to have passwordless logins.

Answer (score 1):

A working example:

a simple script named `hello.sh` that appends to a text file the word hello (uses full paths for each command):

**note** `myuser` is the name of your user

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'hello' >> /home/myuser/hello.txt
```

Make the script executable using `chmod +x hello.sh`

The crontab entry that runs every minute you can change that accordingly to your needs:

```
* * * * * /home/myuser/hello.sh
```

Some details:

- Each cron job runs as the user which registered it. If the root user registers a cron job, this job will run with root privileges.
- If a non root user registers a cron job, this job will run with the aforementioned user's privileges;if the job requires root privileges it will fail because it is initiated by the non root user...
- Better call commands and script using full paths just to be sure that cron can find and call them correctly, else it may fail without useful feedback.

Comment: What you're describing here is exactly what I have in my system. I have a bash script (with execution permissions) run though cron. I used this in a million other situations - the only difference is that I now try to `sftp`. For some reason, this does not work - meaning, the file is not (!) being downloaded from the server or is not placed in home directory. So thanks - but this answer doesn't solve my issue :)

Comment: see @Jakuje comment, if  you are invoking the job as root but the keys are generated for the non root user